# Find all primes $p,q$ and even $n > 2$ such that $p^n+p^{n-1}+\cdots+1 = q^2+q+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Find all primes $p,q$ and even $n > 2$ such that $p^n+p^{n-1}+\cdots+1 = q^2+q+1$.

**Attempt**

The first thing I would do is simplify the geometric series to $\dfrac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} = q^2+q+1$. I was thinking from here we could use a modular arithmetic argument, perhaps using FLT. It is unclear to me though how to proceed since we are working with two different primes.

Comment: To start you could try to write the equation as $p(p^{n}-1) = (p-1)q(q+1)$ and use that $p,q$ are prime to deduce that if $p\not=q$ then $p\mid q+1$ and $q\mid p^n-1$.

Comment: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h29570p182765

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting $1$ from both sides and factoring yields
$$
  p(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\dotsb+1)=q(q+1).
$$
Since $p$ and $q$ are primes, this leads to certain conclusions. Is that enough to go on?

Comment: If you don't have a full solution in mind, then you should've posted this as a comment. Immediately I can see that $p\mid q+1$ and $q\mid p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\cdots+1=(p+1)\left(p^{n-2}+p^{n-4}+\cdots+1\right)$. If $q\mid p+1$, then no solutions, so $q\mid p^{n-2}+p^{n-4}+\cdots+1=\frac{p^n-1}{(p+1)(p-1)}$, so $q\mid p^n-1$.

Comment: @user236182 That's ridiculous. People are allowed to post hints on this website. It's up to the asker to fill in the blanks, unless other people (such as yourself) do it for them.

Comment: @kierenmacmillan I meant "in mind". If you don't know how to solve the problem, then you shouldn't post an answer. People only post "hints" when they know how they could lead to a full solution. There are exceptions when people say "here is some progress:" in their answers to difficult questions.

Comment: I was assuming you don't know how to solve the problem. From the approaches I've seen (see also the link in the comments), the problem doesn't seem simple enough for this to be a decent hint - more like a comment. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein

Comment: Vincenzo's answer is essentially the approach I was thinking of. Once you note that $q+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, things happen pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions can be found deriving a bounding condition on $p$ and $n$. Here's another approach:

Manipulate the equation into $$p\left(p^{n-1}+p^{n-2}+\cdots+1\right)=p\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}=q(q+1) \tag{$\star$}$$ to see there must exist an integer $a>1$ (since $n>2$) such that $$q+1=ap \tag{1}$$and $$ \frac{p^n-1}{p-1}=aq. \tag{2}$$ Subtract $1$ from both sides of $(2)$ to get $$\frac{p^n-p}{p-1}=p\frac{p^{n-1}-1}{p-1}=aq-1, $$ and summing this to $(1)$ we arrive at $$p\left(a+\frac{p^{n-1}-1}{p-1}\right)=q(a+1),$$ whence $a=bp-1$ for some $b\in\mathbb{N^+}$. Substituting into $(\star)$ we finally obtain $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k=(bp-1)(p(bp-1)-1)&=(bp-1)(bp^2-p-1) \\ &=b^2p^3-2bp^2-(b-1)p+1\end{align}$$ and thus $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}p^k=b^2p^2-2bp-b+1 \end{align}$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}p^k=b^2p^2-2bp-b, \tag{3}$$ which shows that $b$ is both a multiple and a divisor of $p$, i.e. $b=p$. Hence $(3)$ is equivalent to $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}p^k&=p^3-2p-1 \\p\left(p^2-2-\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}p^k\right)&=2,\end{align}$$wherefrom we conclude $(n,p,q)=(4,2,5).$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $n=2k$ for some integer $k>1$.  Then we have $q(q+1)=p\left(\frac{p^{2k}-1}{p-1}\right)$.  As $k>1$, $p\neq q$, so that $q$ divides $p^{2k}-1=\left(p^k+1\right)\left(p^k-1\right)$.  That is, $q$ divides either $p^k-1$ or $p^k+1$.  In any case, $q\leq p^k+1$.  Therefore, $$p^{2k}+p^{2k-1}+2< p^{2k}+p^{2k-1}+\ldots+p=q^2+q\leq \left(p^k+1\right)^2+\left(p^k+1\right)=p^{2k}+3p^k+2\,.$$
Ergo, $p^{2k-1}<3p^k$, or $p^{k-1}<3$.  Consequently, $k=2$ and $p=2$.  Hence, the only solution $(p,q,n)$ to $p^n+p^{n-1}+\ldots+p+1=q^2+q+1$ with $p,q,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p$ and $q$ are primes and that $n>2$ is even is $(p,q,n)=(2,5,4)$.

In fact, if $n$ is allowed to be an odd integer greater than $2$, then it follows that $p=2$ (otherwise $p^n+p^{n-1}+\ldots+p+1$ is even, but $q^2+q+1$ is odd).  That is, we are looking for a prime $q$ such that $q^2+q=2^{n+1}-2$, or $(2q+1)^2=2^{n+3}-7$.  As $n$ is odd, $n+3$ is even.  That is, $$\left(2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}-2q-1\right)\left(2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}+2q+1\right)=7\,.$$  Hence, $2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}-2q-1=1$ and $2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}+2q+1=7$.  Consequently, $2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}\leq 6<2^3$.  Thus, $n<3$, which is a contradiction.

In conclusion, the only solution $(p,q,n)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ to $p^n+p^{n-1}+\ldots+p+1=q^2+q+1$ with $p$ and $q$ being prime is $(p,q,n)=(2,5,4)$.